# My question was incorrectly marked as duplicate

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I was told by the support  team that I should post a support question here if I "feel" my question was incorrectly marked as duplicate.

Here's the question:
[Assigning a non-const quoted string to a char*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582702/assigning-a-non-const-quoted-string-to-a-char)

Can someone take a look at it and see what they can do?

Comment: I removed the accusation paragraph of the post, it is not relevant.  And you **should** explain why you don't think it is a duplicate.  You are making a bad assumption that it is obvious to everyone since not every one is a c++ developer

Comment: But if someone can't tell from a glance how they are not duplicates, then they certainly wouldn't even if I explained it. The two questions are completely unrelated and you don't have to be a c++ developer to see that.

Comment: What did you mean with *"and I can't `delete` blocks from it"* then?

Comment: That was the reason why I needed the answer to the original question.

Comment: @user3140280 to not explain the duplicate is your choice, but reopening it stands a much better case when you actually make a good argument, especially when a very respected moderator was the final close vote.

Comment: What argument? If you want me to post a detailed description for each question, then sure I'll do it. But it's not going to be a comparison of the difference between the two questions.

Comment: Very well, let me rephrase that: if your question is not "How to remove characters from a string" then what did you want to achieve with *"`delete` blocks from it"*?

Comment: That part about "deleting blocks" doesn't add anything to the question, I simply added it there because most of the time people will ask "why do you want to do that?" or "why not use this or that".

Comment: That very phrase surely makes it look like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. And without it, well, I'd guess folks would vote for "unclear what you're asking". (But my C/C++ is rusty.)

Comment: I stated more than two times that I don't want the string to become a const char*, the part about deleting them is mentioned only once just to emphasize that a const char(which can't be deleted) is something I don't want.

Comment: There is also the clarification that I added. I don't see how anyone can see this as a question looking for a way to delete characters from a string, when the only clue for such an interpretation is one sentence that was clearly used to emphasize something else.

Comment: @user3140280 actually, it doesn't look like a duplicate to me, but given my unfamiliarity with the language, I'm reluctant to vote to reopen it since I don't know.

Comment: If it's a duplicate, it's a duplicate, but why was it deleted? There were several good answers provided. Voting to undelete.

Comment: The same reason why both of my questions got 5+ downvotes-- users abusing their "powers".

Comment: The linked question got a lot of downvotes because it shows no understanding of C++ at all.  Look at the "purported" duplicate and note that nobody is using `char*` types there.  You also shouldn't be using `char*`.

Comment: Please explain how it shows no understanding of C++. Says no understanding of C++. Yeah, that's how I'm writing a physics engine and just finished a reasonably functional game for testing. And not to mention, without a ton of libraries that do half the work for you.

Comment: @user3140280 Most blatantly, you're trying to `delete` characters from within a character array (and your runtime system is being nice enough to catch the error instead of just crashing your program).  Prior to that, you're attempting to assign one array to another.  To have an array that is assignable from another array, one uses the class `std::array`.  But here, you want an array of characters that you then want to manipulate, and there's a nice built-in class for that, `std::string`.  You're attempting to abuse `C` in your `C++` code.

Comment: I hate using std::string. I'm more comfortable with cstrings and that's irrelevant to the question. The `delete` part is certainly wrong, but that is also irrelevant because to question is not about the use of delete. It was just a slightly incorrect example that was based on an idea that I had at the time, which was wrong in a way.

My question clearly asked for a way to assign the pointer returned by the quoted string to a non-const pointer AND without having it cast to const. I want a method to have the quoted string return a non-const char*.

Comment: To clarify the `delete` part, I incorrectly assumed that I can deallocate each individual `char` in my `char` array.

Comment: As I said.  If you want to program in `C`, program in `C`.  If you're programming in `C++`, you might want to avail yourself of "libraries that do half the work for you."  Such libraries don't contain heinous bugs.

Comment: But how does having C code in your C++ program demonstrate that you lack C++ knowledge?

Comment: That's what you imply by saying that my program lacks fundamental knowledge of C++, when your only provided reasons is the presence a of C-style segment.

Comment: @user3140280 Your "incorrect assumption" is a basic part of the language!  And yes, with some exceptions (that don't apply to your code), having C-style constructs in your code does indeed demonstrate a basic lack of C++ knowledge.  I didn't "imply" that.  I said it outright!

Comment: Let's just say you're right, how does that make it a duplicate of that other, completely unrelated question?

Answer (score 3):

After [consulting with some regulars in The Lounge](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/conversation/discussion-about-http-meta-stackoverflow-com-questions-220062), I reopened the question, and closed it again as "Unclear What You are Asking."

Comment: Ok, this is not as bad as its previous situation.

Comment: Closed is closed.

Comment: Not really. Closed by an annoying little kid and marked incorrectly as duplicate is one thing, closed for not being clear is another and with an understandable reason.